# Why do the CORS settings for my Express.js backend not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I am trying to set CORS for my Express.js backend. Since I have a local and a remote version of the front end I want to allow a couple of URLS access to the backend. I have tried to use "*" and `var cors = require('cors') app.use(cors())` but I get

> Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials
>   flag is true.

I have tried using the dynamic settings for cors(), but there were no examples how to use it with Express's routes. I am now trying to create my own white list check with the code below but now I am getting

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** It looks like the if statement is blocking the headers from being added so I tried to remove it to see what is happening with `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.get("origin"));` It is now giving me

> Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
>   header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials.

```
var whiteList = {
    "http://localhost:5000": true,
    "https://example-url.herokuapp.com": true
};
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {    
        if(whiteList[req.get('Origin')]){            
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.get('Origin'));
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept');        
            next();
        } 
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: _“The response had HTTP status code 500”_ – well that sounds like your headers where not send at all, because you managed to create an error in your code.

Comment: Which Browsers are you seeing this error?  Try more than one.

Comment: @talves Safari has the same result.

Comment: #CBroe I have a feeling that is related to  'if(allowedURLS.indexOf(req.get("origin")) > -1) {' more specifically 'req.get("origin")' I'm just not sure why.

Comment: Is the [`app.use(allowCrossDomain)` above all other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku?answertab=votes#tab-top) `app.use`?

Comment: @talves I had seen that one, and yes I made sure its at the top.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, I don't see where you're using `whitelist`, or where you're setting `àllowedURLS`.

Comment: @l19 the whitelist is the first line in my code example. It is an array of two urls. The allowedURLS, if I understand your meaning,  is set in Access-Control-Allow-Origin on line 4, the first statement inside the if block.

Comment: Shouldn't the 3rd line be `if(whitelist.indexOf(...)`?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, are you sure you're setting the `Origin` header in the request? Have you tried with `if (whiteList[req.headers.host]) {`?

Comment: I'm not sure I am setting it properly, I think that's the problem. req.header.host returns the url of the backend, not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ultimately came down to a spelling/understanding error. I was trying to get the request origin by using `req.headers.Origin`. Turns out there is no 'Origin' in headers, I had to use `req.headers.origin` instead. The code below will work, and let you use multiple URLs for CORS, it does not yet easily handle something like `http://localhost:5000/route` or a situation where the provided origin isn't in the list.

```
var whiteList = {
    "http://localhost:5000": true,
    "https://example-url.herokuapp.com": true
};
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {    
        if(whiteList[req.headers.origin]){            
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Origin, Accept');        
            next();
        } 
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```