# CORS - http OPTIONS error with Angular and Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, cors

I'm trying to make a POST to my API from an Angularjs client, I have this configuration on the server which is running in another domain:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DETELE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  next();
});
```

The headers sent to the server are:

```
OPTIONS /api/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.herokuapp.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5757
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5757/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.8,gl;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
```

The response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DETELE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 47
Etag: W/"2f-5f255986"
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 19:26:56 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

And what I get in the Chrome console is :

```
angular.js:9814 OPTIONS http://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/api/authenticate 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/api/authenticate. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the cors configuration at the very beggining (before bodyParsing, routers, methodOverride, etc.)? have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku Hope it helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact most browsers for security principles does not allow clientside js code to request resource out of same host.

But, it's allowed when resource owner tell to client browser that his sharing resource by adding Cross Origin Resource Sharing headers in response.

To not to guess with headers use cors package - it will do all dirty job for You.

```
npm install cors --save
```

and then:

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

that's all :)

additional docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Can you explain to me what was I doing wrong and why this works?

Comment: cors module does the same as You, but You've not defined most of rules. You can read it here: https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/lib/index.js

Comment: or to check: open chrome and investigate header that cors module sends and write same headers to Your code and remove cors module.

Comment: This answer does not help at all. BTW, - Try this: npm install cors --save ... cors = require('cors') - Are you serious?

Comment: My example is common basic solution. Quick (dirty) solution. It depends on what's Your problem is.

Comment: @GirishRathod nice! (;

Answer (score 1):

I see, that this topic is a little bit older, but I found a little typo in your `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-METHODS`.

Just wanted to share this for other users with a similar problem when they copy & paste:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DETELE
```

There is a typo in `DELETE`.