# How to upload picture on c9 server via website

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Im using IDE Cloud9 and Angular, I can't figure out how do I upload pictures on my c9, like, I have input, so when user uploads the image, it goes on c9 server and keeps in some 'uploads' folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omni,
you can use multer npm for uploading file with angular js and node api. Please refer below link for more details,

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer
2. [nodejs + multer + angularjs for uploading without redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957006/nodejs-multer-angularjs-for-uploading-without-redirecting)
3. https://ciphertrick.com/2015/12/07/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs/

Comment: Yeah, that's worked for me on my desktop, but how do I use this at c9? Should I make another project for launching the node server?

Comment: host ur application on c9 server and test it.

Comment: alright, I hosted my node there, and my angular2 project, but it tells me that (Response for preflight is invalid (redirect))

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683603/cors-http-options-error-with-angular-and-express

Comment: you should learn about resolving error, here other members can guide/help you to resolved problem but no one will sit here and resolved your problem with implementing all solutions.