# Restricting CORS origin with Node/Express not working

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, http-headers, cors

I'm trying to restrict the origin of CORS requests to one specific domain per route using the [express.js CORS package](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

let app = express();

app.get('/', cors({origin: 'http://example.com'}), (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('/', cors({origin: 'http://whatever.com'}) (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started on port ${port}`);
});
```

This doesn't seem to have any effect, however, as I'm able to `GET` and `POST` from any domain. I then tried instead to restrict all routes to one single origin using the following, but met the same results:

```
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://example.com'}));
```

I'm experiencing this both in my dev environment on localhost and my production environment on Heroku. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku?rq=1 allow access control should be set to site from where u want to accept the request i think

Comment: @Rico what should I be doing to only allow `POST` requests to come from a certain domain, for example?

Comment: res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');  << keep only post here

Comment: that will still allow any origin to POST. I'm not concerned with the method as much as the origin

Comment: res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http:/ricoGotSwag.com');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'); << should only allow post requests from ricoGotSwag.com << i used one / in the url cos if i use 2 then it gets converted to a link

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers << all about http headers

Comment: hm I tried that as well, and that's supposed to do the same thing as using this express CORS package

Comment: see this answer (and compare to the one above it): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21622564/1179207

Comment: What `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value is the server sending in responses? To test, you can emulate a browser by using Postman or curl to send an `Origin` header with whatever value you want to test: `curl -i -H "Origin: https://some-not-allowed-origin" https://your-express-site`

Comment: so in the accepted answer they say to move app.use(cors({origin: 'http://example.com'})); to top in configure method

Comment: @sideshowbarker doesnt dev tools in chrome allow to see the headers of the requets sent under network tab?

Comment: @sideshowbarker using that curl command (as well as Postman) returns Access-Control-Allow-Origin → http://example.com, but the request returns a successful 200 code nonetheless and my server processes it

Comment: @Rico yes when I used app.use(cors({...}) as described in the question it was at the top

Comment: ok, try this code, i will post it in answer to make it look pretty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your server is sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com` response header, then you actually already have it configured correctly.

It’s expected behavior for the server to return a 200 response no matter what origin you make the request from—even for those from an origin other than the configured `http://example.com`

The CORS settings don’t cause the server to block requests from any clients.

Instead, if the server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com` to a client request from JavaScript code in a web app that’s not running at `http://example.com`, then the *browser* blocks that JavaScript code from being able to access the response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS gives more details.

Basically the way it works is that from the server side, no behavior changes other than the difference in what response headers it sends. So the server will receive the request just as it otherwise would, and will send the response just as it otherwise would.

And then the browser will receive the response just as it otherwise would. You will be able to see the response in your browser devtools and examine it there. But that does not mean the browser will expose the response to your client-side JavaScript code.

Instead, the browser checks the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header from the server and will only expose the response cross-origin to your origin if the server says it should be allowed to: Your browser checks the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` against your actual origin, and if it either matches exactly or the value is `*` to allow any origin, only then does the browser allow your client-side JavaScript code to access the response.

Comment: ah ok I see where I got confused. so is there a recommended way for my server to check the origin of requests and act accordingly based on that?

Comment: var ref = req.headers.referer; //req.headers.origin;
  if(ref==something) {
   do this
  }
  else {
   do that
  }

Comment: The answer to that question depends on what you mean by “act accordingly” but regardless, that seems like something you probably want to post separately as a different question from this one. It seems like you have an answer to the particular question you posted here—I mean, as far as the explanation for why you’re seeing the behavior you’re seeing and  whether your express CORS configuration is working as expected (it is) or if you’ve made some mistake in the config (you haven’t) or it’s broken in some way (it’s not).