# CORS not working

Tags: angular, http-status-code-503

I have a contact form that the user fills out which gets posted to my Web API to be sent using `nodemailer`.

CORS works as expected with the when I run the client and API locally:

**Client**

localhost:4200
with POST request

```
sendEmail(queryObject: any) {
const body = JSON.stringify(queryObject);
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/sendemail', body, {headers: headers})
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

**API**

localhost:3000

but as soon as I deploy my API to heroku and change the POST URL in the client to point to Heroku I get the preflight error:

> OPTIONS https://keilcarpenter-portfolioapi.herokuapp.com/api/sendemail 503 (Service Unavailable)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://keilcarpenter-portfolioapi.herokuapp.com/api/sendemail. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

I am sure I have CORS set up properly in server.js on my API:

```
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Why is CORS accepting the POST locally but not on Heroku?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow CORS REST request to a Express/Node.js application on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku)

Comment: Also note that stringifying to json and adding the json content-type header is unnecessary. Just post the object, and angular will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, when you deploy a webapp or an app from differents port will make you deal with `CORS`, so you will need to configurate the server to be more friendly and accept `CORS`(makes you acept request form different origins). In tomcat modify web.xml, firebase do another thing, on azure the same etc... every serve has his own config.
But in `angular` is the same, you must config a proxy to bypass these port problems.
So create an proxy.conf.json like this

```
{
  "/angular": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "github.com",
       "protocol": "https:",
       "port": 443
     },
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

and then create a script like this in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

and then instead run `ng serve` run `ng start` or `npm start`

Really nice documnets about this:

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1896/commits/a81aa3b6117848a1c9c99d3b6d0666433b5144e0