# How to get data from rest api which has basic authentication?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restful-authentication

I'm trying to get data from this website through HTTP get method. This website has basic authentication. The data is in JSON format. 
This is the rest api website:
(https://shoploapi.herokuapp.com/sellers)

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('myapp', ['myapp.controller']);

angular.module('myapp.controller', ['myapp.service'])
  .controller('testController', function($scope, testService) {

    $scope.posts = {};

    function GetAllPosts() {
      var getPostsData = testService.getPosts();

      getPostsData.then(function(post) {
        $scope.posts = post.data;

      }, function() {
        alert('Error in getting post records');
      });
    }

    GetAllPosts();
  });

angular.module('myapp.service', [])
  .service('testService', function($http) {

    //get All NewsLetter
    this.getPosts = function() {
      return $http.get('https://shoploapi.herokuapp.com/sellers');
    };
  });
angular.module('myApp', ['base64'])
  .config(function($httpProvider, $base64) {
    var auth = $base64.encode("bhupendra7:ice123age456");
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + auth;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
          {{post.careof}} {{post.district}} {{post.gender}} {{post.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the link to my Plunker:

(https://plnkr.co/edit/7pqljm?p=preview)

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have a typo in `angular.module('myApp', ['base64'])` make `myApp` to `myapp` .. Even if that's corrected you will face another problem, testController being `undefined`. Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code.

**1. You have a typo**

In `angular.module('myApp', ['base64'])`, change to module name to `myapp`

**2. The way you have injected your `myapp.controller` to `myapp` module**

Change it to `angular.module('myapp', []);` You will also need to reorder your code. Check out the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6EU2uR) I have created for you.

Even if you fix the above two problems, you will still face a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem from Heroku. Depending on your server-side technology (NodeJS, Rails etc.), you will need to enable it from the server to be able to communicate with your app. You can also look in to [JSONP with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066002/parsing-jsonp-http-jsonp-response-in-angular-js)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thnak you sir. Can you please help me. I've been trying it for a long time. What will I have to do inorder to get the data?

Comment: On what technology have you written your server application?

Comment: The server application is written on nodejs. Mongodb is used as database and and Expressjs is used as web framework.

Comment: Check this link to configure CORS with ExpressJS:
https://github.com/expressjs/cors

A more specific question related to Heroku and NodeJS+Express:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku