# Angular 5: How to handle cases when Rest API redirects to URLs outside domain?

Tags: angular, rest

I have my angular 5 app and Java Rest APIs deployed in the same Jetty container (same server and same port).

I have a rest API, which if accessed without authentication, is redirected to SSO (external domain), user logs in and user is redirected back to called rest api. This flow is working fine if the api is accessed directly from browser.

However, I am not able to figure out how to do the same with my angular app.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:4400/api/test/sso',
                { observe: 'response' })                                
                .subscribe(
                  res => {
                    console.log("SSO respnse= "+res);
                  } ,error => {
                      console.error(error);
                  }                 
                );
```

Nothing happens.

However,hitting http://localhost:4400/api/test/sso directly in browser works as expected and redirection happens without any issue.

Also, the other Rest api that return a simple response are working fine from angular app. It is just this api which  redirects to an outside domain, which is not working from angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and found that the best way for my use case is to redirect the browser to my rest api instead of using httpclient to make the `get` request.

```
window.location.href =  http://localhost:4400/api/test/sso //i.e. url of rest api
```

After the authentication flow completes, the api can redirect back to a certain specific route of angular app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CORS properties for response headers for server on external domain

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
```

The simplest way to do it on nodejs as follows:

```
var cors = require('cors'); app.use(cors());
```

Please look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku) for details

Comment: CORS is already there on external server which is the reason why I am able to make a request by directly entering the rest api url in browser. Problem comes when I am trying to make the request from angular app(which is on the same domain as rest api)

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Authorization:Bearer eyJhb
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:19
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 30 Jan 2018 10:30:20 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Jetty(9.2.10.v20150310)
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered starting your app with `--host` and `--proxy-config`(*) flags and starting your sso service also on the same host, so you could actually do some less problematic development?

(*) ofc proper config.json will be needed

Comment: I am using OKTA for SSO so i don't have a flexibility of bringing it on samehost. I build angular app and then deploy it on Jetty.