# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource (express + react/redux)

Tags: express, heroku, redux, cors, fetch

I'm getting this error on my React app. "Failed to load https://app-name.herokuapp.com/users/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

Code in my Express app

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();

 router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Accept");
      next();
  }
```

Code in my Redux fetch call

```
 return dispatch => {
    const url = "https://app-name.herokuapp.com/users/";
    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
    })
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(res => res.json())....
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an issue with your WebService, that happens when you are pointing from a domain to a different domain, like I'm pointing from localhost:3000 to localhost:3001, those are different, you should enable CORS in your WebService to allow that request.

You have to look for a way to enable CORS in your Heroku app, as I know, the external API calls are blocked in free domains, but don't know with Heroku.

Comment: So should my port in my heroku be pointing to 3001 too? Because that's what's happening in my react app

Comment: You should allow CORS in your Heroku app.
Maybe it could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku

Comment: I have a public fetch API. But some people were telling to enable CORS as it blocks their requests. I know there is an npm package called cors. 
But I saw that many Public APIs do not have CORS enabled. I also read some articles about the security risks in CORS.

**I was asking that will it be wrong to enable CORS**. Few people are calling the API from the client-side code that is running in the browsers.
Any suggestion is gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I had to do was push to my heroku app. I didn't know it had its own git repo. Facepalm.