# Apollo Client sending OPTIONS instead of GET HTTP method

Tags: javascript, meteor, graphql, apollo-client

I'm having trouble understanding Apollo Client library as it does not work as intended. Instead of sending the **`GET`** HTTP method, it sends the **`OPTIONS`** HTTP method even though I've put to use **GET** only when retrieving data from GraphQL server.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        new MeteorAccountsLink(),
        new HttpLink({
            uri: 'https://selo-comments.herokuapp.com/graphql',
            useGETForQueries: true
        })
    ]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Console log from the browser:

`OPTIONS https://selo-comments.herokuapp.com/graphql?query=%7B%0A%20%20comments(id%3A%20%22TFpQmhrDxQqHk2ryy%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20articleID%0A%20%20%20%20content%0A%20%20%20%20userId%0A%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20commentID%0A%20%20%20%20votes%0A%20%20%20%20blockedUsers%0A%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&variables=%7B%7D 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Which obviously means that the HTTP method is incorrect even if it has the query parameter in the url. If you query that url using Postman or simply navigating to the url using browser's address bar, you will get GraphQL data. I have to use `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` in order to execute the query successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The options request is probably a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS).

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood.
>   It is an OPTIONS request, using three HTTP request headers: Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the Origin header.

You probably need to configure your server to allow cross origin calls.

Maybe you can find some inspiration here to get u started. [Allow CORS REST request to a Express/Node.js application on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku)

Comment: Wow, that actually fixed the problem haha. I wasn't even aware of this, thank you!

Comment: I already had a CORS module on the server but it was still giving me headaches on the client side, but thanks again.