# JavaScript Axios GET data= null

Tags: javascript, get, null, axios, response

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can not find the reason.

I try to perform a GET using axios, which if I do it from postman the answer is correct, but from axios it returns the data to null.

Postman:

```
{
    "direccion": "Castelldefels, Spain",
    "lat": "41.279999",
    "lng": "1.970000"
}
```

Code JS:

```
var boton = document.getElementById('location');
boton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    loading.style.display = 'block';
    axios.get('https://restserver-test-jsg.herokuapp.com/location?location=Castelldefels', {
            responseType: 'json',
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            if (res.status == 200) {

                console.log(res);

                mensaje.innerHTML = res.data;
            }
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .then(function() {
            loading.style.display = 'none';
        });
});
```

The answer I see from the Chrome console is:
[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmW1E.png)

If I perform this operation from the browser, it returns what was expected.
https://restserver-test-jsg.herokuapp.com/location?location=Castelldefels

Thank you!

Comment: Please ask the question in English

Comment: Thank for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just a syntax error with axios?  There probably shouldn't be a comma after the responseType key in the configuration object.

Edit:

Ah, I see.  It looks to be a CORS error with heroku.  Check this question for the answer: [Allow CORS REST request to a Express/Node.js application on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001817/allow-cors-rest-request-to-a-express-node-js-application-on-heroku)